# initializing static array problem

Tags: variables, static

I am making a server-client and the client repeatedly calls the server files.  I am supposed to save the message the client sent in a char array.  In the server files, each time the client sends something the char array (static variable) gets overwritten with what it is assigned to in the function of that file.  How do I initialize the static variable char array to all '\0' before going into the function in the file?  Is that the right thing to do in the first place? I feel silly going char array[100] = 'dddddddddd...  Plus, the length value is unknown.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thinking about it more, I think (the function that overwrites the static variables is in another file) I should declare the static variables in the encompassing file and pass the char arrays as parameters to the function.

Comment: You didn't mention the language.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? I'm not too familiar with server programming, but a lot of languages adopt syntax from C, and in C it would be `static char array[100] = {0};`.